# How to check type forwarding for type in mscorlib to system.runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.5

I'm analysing code at runtime and the IObservable appears to be coming from the System.Runtime assembly when running in a .Net 4.5 application.

Now I know IObservable is defined in mscorlib ([system namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx)).

I've read about TypeForwardedToAttribute & TypeForwardedFromAttribute attributes and understand the principle.

**But how do I check for usage of these attributes and importantly where?**

I tried reflecting the mscorlib to find either of these attributes but could not find there usage - see example code below:

```
 var assembly = typeof (IObservable<>).Assembly;

 var tmp = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(a => a is TypeForwardedToAttribute).ToList();
 var tmp2 = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(a => a is TypeForwardedFromAttribute).ToList();

 var tmp3 = typeof (IObservable<>).GetCustomAttributesData();

 var tmp4 = typeof(IObservable<>).GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(a => a is TypeForwardedToAttribute).ToList();
 var tmp5 = typeof(IObservable<>).GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(a => a is TypeForwardedFromAttribute).ToList();

 var tmp6 = typeof(IObservable<>).GetCustomAttributesData();

 var tmp7 = typeof (IObservable<>).Attributes;
```

Comment: You have to look at the *reference assemblies* to see the greater scheme.  The mscorlib.dll reference assembly for a Store or PCL project is a good one to look at.  Note how it contains no types at all, only [TypeForwarded] attributes.  It gets redirected back at runtime.

Comment: You can download the relevant reference assemblies here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/hh487283.aspx